# Curl Download for Paypal

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I am looking over the docs to setup the Paypal pro integration and it says to copy in the curl code (which I have never even heard of curl). Then it says to download it onto your computer. Should I actually download it onto my hosted server??

I am confused with what to do in regards to this and could someone please explain what the curl code does?

Here is the link to the curl site. Which one should I even download?

http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Here is the paypal page I was referring to, the curl reference is in the "Try It" section:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/gs_PayPalPaymentsPro/?mark=paypal%20pro

```
METHOD : DoDirectPayment
PAYMENTACTION : SALE
AMT : // price

// credit card details
ACCT, CREDITCARDTYPE, CVV2, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, STREET, CITY, STATE, ZIP, COUNTRYCODE, EXPDATE


curl -s --insecure https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp -d "USER=platfo_1255077030_biz_api1.gmail.com&PWD=1255077037&SIGNATURE=Abg0gYcQyxQvnf2HDJkKtA-p6pqhA1k-KTYE0Gcy1diujFio4io5Vqjf&METHOD=DoDirectPayment&VERSION=78&PAYMENTACTION=SALE&AMT=5&ACCT=4660997962602322&CREDITCARDTYPE=VISA&CVV2=176&FIRSTNAME=James&LASTNAME=Smith&STREET=FirstStreet&CITY=SanJose&STATE=CA&ZIP=95131&COUNTRYCODE=US&EXPDATE=092015"
```

Comment: You can make all transaction process using curl

Comment: But it seems the code for the curl has static place holders in it that paypal provided? And do you know how I can download it? I updated my question to show the code of the curl.

Comment: `curl` is a "very-well-know" piece of software that is part and parcel of `php` programming. You really need to spend some time reading about it, as if you're going to be a web programmer, it is going to be your #1 way of transfering data and files between systems. There is virtually no risk downloading from the site listed. Whether it is permitted to download to your hosted server you will only find out by trying. It is very likely that your hosting company already has curl available, and you just need to add the dir to your PATH. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I host with hostgator . How could I tell if it is available? Then how could I add its directory to my path? Sorry for the newb questions.

Comment: You need to learn how to communicate with the support team at hostgator. They should answer these Qs for you. I have no knowledge of specifics of working with hostgator. You need to look for help/support/open ticket on their site. Sounds like you still have a lot to learn. Maybe you should reset expectations with your client about when this project will be done ;-( . Sorry, but Good luck.

Comment: I don't have a client I am working with to do this. I am just trying to figure out how to do it.

Comment: @shellter I contacted hostgator and it seems they have curl in their servers, They provided me with this article: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/curl ... The only part I am slightly confused on is this part: How to Use cURL

You will need SSH access to your account if you wish to manage cURL directly via the command line. ................ Do I need to do any of that or will the server automatically detect when I have curl code in my file?

Comment: Think about what this means " You will need SSH access to your account if you wish to manage cURL directly via the command line". Do you understand that? (sorry, not trying to be rude, but getting ssh working can be maddening (the first 2-5 times you do it) ). Ask the support team for any/all info they have on `ssh`. You will need it and you'll need to study and make an attempt to solve your own problem before you can expect to get help here on StackOverlow. Once you have more reputation points (by good Qs or As), you can use the chat system here on S.O. to ask these openended Qs, . . .

Comment: Please read the FAQ and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to learn how to construct meaningful Qs that are in scope on all of StackExchange sites. I won't be able to continue further on this line. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter No offense, but I whole-heartedly disagree with you. I do not feel my question is bad, what-so-ever. Not everyone has the same skill-set/knowledge base. I searched this before posting and found nothing on it. Therefore, I am sure many other members that are new to this subject may run across this. I was confused with the ssh part because I am only doing this for a paypal api. When I see 'command line', I think of the command function on a computer. 

Anyways, you have rested your case and are no longer willing to help. I appreciate the advise you gave.

Comment: No offence taken, I understand how frustrating getting some new technology to work can be (believe me!). I have not downvoted your Q or voted to close, so I respect that  you have spent some time trying to solve your problem. As I said, curl is a major component of php programming. Try searching here for `[php] curl` You'll get 1000s of hits. Getting it work with ssh is more difficult, but you'll need to post what you have tried. . . .

Comment: @shellter After you expressed how major of a componenet was, I went onto youtube and emailed myself some tutorials to help learn it. I do mostly front-end work and intermediate php, so I don't usually get into this kind of level of it. I was told paypal was easy to integrate, so I went with that route, but want to use their pro service so the customer never leaves my site and this is the first time I have even seen/heard curl mentioned. Anyways, thanks again.

Comment: For starts in your `$HOME/.bash_profile` add `export PATH="/path/to/curl/install/dir:$PATH". Maybe your curl code will start emitting helpful error messages (but I can't guarantee it). Good luck.

Comment: BTW, the instructions for downloading SSH seem pretty simple. How Do I Connect to My Server via SSH?

Below are instructions on how to connect to a server via SSH with various operating systems.

Windows OS

To access SSH:

Download WinSCP or PuTTY.
Enter your IP address and the appropriate port number.
Shared and Reseller accounts - Port 2222
Dedicated and VPS - Port 22
Log in with your cPanel username and password. Dedicated and VPS customers have the option of logging in with the root WHM username and password.
Linux OS

Comment: lol . I hope it works for you that easily! Good luck and bye for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    $clientt="";
    $secrett="";
     $ch = curl_init();
     //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");    //https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");    //https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientt.":".$secrett);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $json = json_decode($result);

     $data = '{
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "credit_card",
    "funding_instruments": [
      {
        "credit_card": {
          "number": "'.$CardNumber1.'",
          "type": "'.$CardType1.'",
          "expire_month": "'.$ExpirationMonth.'",
          "expire_year": "'.$ExpirationYear.'",
          "cvv2": "'.$ccv.'",
          "first_name": "'.$FirstName1.'",
          "last_name": "'.$LastName1.'"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "'.$donate_amount.'",
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "description": "This is the payment transaction description."
    }
  ]
}';

    $ch1 = curl_init();
    //curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment");      //https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment");      //https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json","Authorization: Bearer ".$json->access_token));
     $result1 = curl_exec($ch1);
```

Please change variables and also mode sandbox

Comment: Is this for the NVP/SOAP API that can be used for the pro payment accounts?